# How to create list of array combinations lexographically in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this array and I want to return unique array combinations. I tried meshgrid but it creates duplicates and inverse array values

```
>> import numpy as np
>> array = np.array([0,1,2,3])
>> combinations = np.array(np.meshgrid(array, array)).T.reshape(-1,2)
>> print(combinations)

[[0 0] 
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 3]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [2 2]
 [2 3]
 [3 0]
 [3 1]
 [3 2]
 [3 3]]
```

What I want to exclude are the **repeating arrays**: `[0,0] [1,1] [2,2] [3,3]` and the **inverse arrays** `when [2,3] is returned exclude [3,2] in the output`.

Take a look at this combination calculator, [this is the output that I like](https://planetcalc.com/3757/?set=%5B%7B%22value%22%3A%220%22%2C%22pkID%22%3A%2228746%22%2C%22save_label%22%3A%22%22%2C%22cancel_label%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%221%22%2C%22pkID%22%3A%2228747%22%2C%22save_label%22%3A%22%22%2C%22cancel_label%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%222%22%2C%22pkID%22%3A%22%22%2C%22save_label%22%3A%22%22%2C%22cancel_label%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22value%22%3A%223%22%2C%22pkID%22%3A%22%22%2C%22save_label%22%3A%22%22%2C%22cancel_label%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D&Msize=2) but how can I create it in NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `combinations` from itertools

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

array = np.array([0,1,2,3])
combs = np.array(list(combinations(arr, 2)))
```